# How to select data using mysql database using a query?

Tags: android, mysql, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I made a statement, but this does not work. I need some help to find an issue.

I am working with RecyclerView on android but I do not want to receive data from police number 100. how to do it?

This my php file.

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ariac1083461");


$sql = "SELECT Numero_Client,ASSURE,branche,Police,Type,Du,Effet,Code_agence,Echeance,Prime_Nette,accessoires,cemac,periode,PTTC,compagnie FROM etat_cima_arrieres WHERE Police != 100";
$table=array();
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $table[]=$row;
    }
    print json_encode($table);

}
else
{
    echo "Pas de valeurs<br /><br />";
}

?>
```

Comment: By "not working"...It does what?

Comment: i want to retrieve data but not where police number = 100. police is a number for my insurance app.

Comment: Use the ``<>`` operator instead of ``!=`` in your SQL query.

Comment: i dont understand could you explain clearly?

Comment: @DelphiCoder means "SELECT Numero_Client,.... FROM etat_cima_arrieres WHERE Police **<>** 100"